# Running h2o, rsparkling, sparklyr

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, h2o, sparklyr

I have been trying to run Spark 2.2, `master=yarn` with h2o(`rsparkling`) but when I run `h2o_context(sc)` I get exception:

```
Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getUserJars(Lorg/apache/spark/SparkConf;Z)Lscala/collection/Seq;
    at org.apache.spark.repl.h2o.H2OInterpreter.createSettings(H2OInterpreter.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.h2o.BaseH2OInterpreter.initializeInterpreter(BaseH2OInterpreter.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.h2o.BaseH2OInterpreter.<init>(BaseH2OInterpreter.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.h2o.H2OInterpreter.<init>(H2OInterpreter.scala:42)
    at water.api.scalaInt.ScalaCodeHandler.createInterpreterInPool(ScalaCodeHandler.scala:100)
    at water.api.scalaInt.ScalaCodeHandler$$anonfun$initializeInterpreterPool$1.apply(ScalaCodeHandler.scala:94)
    at water.api.scalaInt.ScalaCodeHandler$$anonfun$initializeInterpreterPool$1.apply(ScalaCodeHandler.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
    at water.api.scalaInt.ScalaCodeHandler.initializeInterpreterPool(ScalaCodeHandler.scala:93)
    at water.api.scalaInt.ScalaCodeHandler.<init>(ScalaCodeHandler.scala:37)
    at water.api.scalaInt.ScalaCodeHandler$.registerEndpoints(ScalaCodeHandler.scala:132)
    at water.api.CoreRestAPI$.registerEndpoints(CoreRestAPI.scala:32)
    at water.api.RestAPIManager.register(RestAPIManager.scala:39)
    at water.api.RestAPIManager.registerAll(RestAPIManager.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalH2OBackend.init(InternalH2OBackend.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.init(H2OContext.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext$.getOrCreate(H2OContext.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext$.getOrCreate(H2OContext.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.getOrCreate(H2OContext.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've also tried spark 2.0.0 (installed via `sparklyr` function: `spark_install`). And then match with rsparkling and h2o. It worked when I set `master="local"`, however it gave the same error when I set `master="yarn"`

Similarly I tried Spark 1.6 and it worked fine (also `master=yarn`).

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(rsparkling)
library(h2o)


Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='/usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/spark2')

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn")
h2o_context(sc)
```

I've tried to install various different versions of h2o using(similar) install.packages("h2o", type = "source", repos = "http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tverberg/2/R") but each time the error doesn't change.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396621/install-rsparkling-sparkling-water-nightly-bleeding-edge/51931503#51931503) might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bug report! It should already be fixed in the master branch of Sparkling Water and it will be part of the next release (ETA is next week).

Thanks,
Navdeep