# Install rsparkling - Sparkling water Nightly Bleeding Edge

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install the latest version of Sparkling Water that is compatible with my versions of h2o and Spark, from the following link [Sparklin Water Nightly Bleeding Edge](https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/sparkling-water/master/259_nightly/index.html)

*I'm trying the following code:*

```
install.packages("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/sparkling-water/master/259_nightly/sparkling-water-2.3.259_nightly.zip",repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")    

#install.packages('C:/Users/USER/Downloads/sparkling-water-2.3.259_nightly.zip',repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

But it throws the following error

> Warning in install.packages :   cannot open compressed file
>   'sparkling-water-2.3.258_nightly/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No
>   such file or directory' Error in install.packages : cannot open the
>   connection

The latest stable version of rsparkling on CRAN can be installed as follows:

```
install.packages("rsparkling")
```

The installation works, but apparently it is not compatible with my version of h2o and / or Spark, because it does not work `as_h2o_frame` function from *rsparkling*.

What can I do? To use rsparkling with my version of h2o

**Note**

- R Version: 3.4.4
- `packageVersion("sparklyr")` is **‘0.8.0’**
- `packageVersion("h2o")` is **‘3.21.0.4359’**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue after going through quite a few trial-and-errors.

The first point is to make sure that you have got the right version of Java installed on your computer. Specifically, Java versions 9 and 10 can be problematic see [here](https://github.com/uc-cfss/Discussion/issues/71). I got Java SE Development Kit 8u172 installed. To make sure what Java version you have got installed and running, in your Terminal type:

```
 java -version
```

Next, based on the table given [here](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/master/r), I found a sweet compatibility spot between `h2o` version 3.18.0.11 with `spark` version 2.3.0 and `Sparkling Water` version 2.3.6.

So, install the following packages:
- for h20 (version 3.18.0.11):

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/h2o/h2o_3.18.0.11.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

- for sparklyr (version 0.8.4) and rsparkling (version 0.2.5):

```
install.packages(c("sparklyr","rsparkling"))
```

Then, first configure the appropriate version of Sparkling Water before calling library(rsparkling). So, the rest of the code becomes:

```
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.3.6") 

library(rsparkling)  
library(sparklyr)  
library(h2o)
```

Now, you should be able to go ahead and install the Spark version 2.3.0, and the rest:

```
spark_install(version = "2.3.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.0")

mtcars_tbl <- copy_to(sc, mtcars, "mtcars")
mtcars_h2o <- as_h2o_frame(sc, mtcars_tbl, strict_version_check = FALSE)
```

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Thanks `sm1231` for the help, but I need to install the version of sparkling water Nightly Bleeding Edge, in Spark 2.3.1, in his case I work with other versions.