# Install latest Sparkling Water Version

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, h2o

I am following the installation guide for Sparkling Water but it does not work at all. It consists of 8 steps as you can see in: [rsparkling](https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/sparkling-water/master/259_nightly/index.html)

[image]

- First problem from  Step 2 install an old version of sparklyr *(not compatible with Spark 2.3.1)*, solved using `install.packages("https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/archive/v0.8.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`
- Step 3, version 2.3.1 of Spark is not available as shown by the command `sparklyr::spark_available_versions() #2.3.0`. Solved installing directly from the page [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).
- Step 6 does not work, install an unsupported version of `rsparkling` with h2o, `packageVersion("h2o") #'3.21.0.4359'`

I'm trying to do the following, download the latest version of sparkling water, unzip the file. And use the following code:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/sparkling-water-2.3.259_nightly/rsparkling.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package 'rsparkling' ...
** package 'rsparkling' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rsparkling)
In R CMD INSTALL
```

Up to here everything seems fine.

```
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.3.259_nightly")
library(rsparkling)
# 7. Connect to Spark
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local")
Error: invalid version specification ‘2.3.259_nightly’
```

> Error: invalid version specification ‘2.3.259_nightly’

**Note:**
Download [Sparkling Water Nightly Bleeding Edge](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4364/h2o-3.21.0.4364.zip) version.
The packages h2o, SparkR, sparklyr and the connections work correctly on windows 7 R version 3.4.4, I only have problems with `rsparkling`.

```
system('spark-submit --version')
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_151
Branch 
Compiled by user vanzin on 2018-06-01T20:37:04Z
```

As I can solve this problem, I have installed the appropriate version of **rsparkling**, compatible with the latest version of **h2o**.

**Edit question:** Well Lauren thanks for the links, now I'm working with the latest stable version of h2o 3.20.0.5 and spparkling water. But apparently I think the problem will not be with the rsparkling package, but with the sparklyr package, as the last version of apache spark 2.3.1 was released (Jun 08 2018), while the latest update of sparklyr 0.8.4 was (May 25 2018) that is, it was launched a month earlier (*spark 2.3.1 did not exist*). Therefore the command:

```
spark_available_versions()
   spark
1  1.6.3
2  1.6.2
3  1.6.1
4  1.6.0
5  2.0.0
6  2.0.1
7  2.0.2
8  2.1.0
9  2.1.1
10 2.2.0
11 2.2.1
12 2.3.0

# Set spark connection
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.1") #It does not work
Error in spark_install_find(version, hadoop_version, latest = FALSE, hint = TRUE) : 
Spark version not installed. To install, use spark_install(version = "2.3.1")
spark_install(version = "2.3.1")
Error in spark_install_find(version, hadoop_version, installed_only = FALSE,  : 
Spark version not available. Find available versions, using spark_available_versions()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local") #it works perfectly
```

I think the solution will be waiting for sparklyr 0.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install last version sparklyr and connect to Spark

```
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "2.3.2")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.2")
```

Install H2O of correct version:

```
install.packages("h2o", type = "source", repos = "https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wright/10/R")
packageVersion("h2o")
[1] ‘3.20.0.10’
```

Verify the compatibility of sparkling water with h2o

```
rsparkling::h2o_release_table()[1:5,]
   Spark_Version Sparkling_Water_Version H2O_Version H2O_Release_Name H2O_Release_Patch_Number
1            2.3                  2.3.16   3.20.0.10       rel-wright                       10
17           2.3                  2.3.15    3.20.0.9       rel-wright                        9
16           2.3                  2.3.14    3.20.0.8       rel-wright                        8
15           2.3                  2.3.13    3.20.0.7       rel-wright                        7
14           2.3                  2.3.12    3.20.0.6       rel-wright                        6
```

Set Sparkling Water version to be used with RSparkling

```
options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.3.16")
library(rsparkling)
```

Now, H2OContext is available and we can use any H2O features available in R.
    h2o_context(sc)
    
      org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext

```
Sparkling Water Context:
 * H2O name: sparkling-water-USER_local-1539839100465
 * cluster size: 1
 * list of used nodes:
  (executorId, host, port)
  ------------------------
  (driver,127.0.0.1,54321)
  ------------------------

  Open H2O Flow in browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321 (CMD + click in Mac OSX)

h2o_flow(sc)
```

Initialize [Spark UI](http://localhost:4040)

[image]

**Now the integration of Spark with H2O through Sparkling Water works perfectly.**

Answer (score 1):

The nightly downloads page is meant to work for simple environments, and is not meant to capture all possible configurations.

However, since this question is specific to Windows, you can find documentation on how to Use Sparkling Water in Windows Environments [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.3/latest-stable/doc/deployment/run_on_windows.html#run-on-windows) and how to Use Rsparkling in Windows Environments [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.3/latest-stable/doc/deployment/rsparkling_on_windows.html) (note these are for the latest stable, but the instructions should be similar for the nightly release).

Answer (score 0):

Although your question was specific to Windows, you may want to try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931503/10247576) that worked fine in Mac.